# React js showing different date then passed from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing a plain date as string from api, something like `2022-04-24`, but on front react, it is parsing the date to the local timezone, which I don't want to be parsed to local timezone. My code on react looks like:

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import ReactDatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
export function App() {
  const schema = Yup.object({});

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    control
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const onSubmit = async (input) => {
    console.log("input", input);
  };

  const item = {
    id: 12,
    release_date: "2022-04-24"
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="release_date"
        defaultValue={item.release_date ? new Date(item.release_date) : null}
        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
          <ReactDatePicker
            onChange={onChange}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            className="form-control w-full"
            dateFormat="MMM dd, yyyy"
            selected={value}
          />
        )}
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here is the screenshot,

[image]

Currently, it is showing `apr 23`, even when I had passed it `04-24`. To see the issue, you might have to use some different timezone (where still current date is `apr 23`).

And, here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-example-wfvcmu?file=/src/App.js:0-1132)

Comment: Have you looked into using moment js ?

Comment: you want it to be shown in this format `04-12-2022` ?? If not what's the format you want it to be shown

Comment: @BARNOWL I am open to use moment js if it could offer, what I need. Could you please suggest the possible answer

Comment: @Codenewbie its not format, format is fine with me as `apr 24`, or `04-24` as well, its the date, you can see instead of showing `24`, its showing `23`

Comment: My bad ... gotcha

Comment: @Codenewbie do you have any suggestion on this one?

Comment: Not really @AayushDahal, but please take a look at this [Q - Which says to use a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751698/stop-javascript-date-function-from-changing-timezone-offset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a different when you use `-` and `/`

```js
const date1 = new Date("2022/04/24");
const date2 = new Date("2022-04-24");

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<h4>${date1}</h4>
<h4>${date2}</h4>
`;
```

```html
<div id="app">
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/date-object-qqjnrs

Comment: I couldn't get it because, I am using `-` itself instead of `/`. Could you please share your sandbox code by forking from above link?

Comment: @AayushDahal 
I have added a link to the code sand box, hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Luxon implementation: (from the same people who build moment)

https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon

```
// leave it as a string
const date1 = "2022-04-24"; 
const date2 = "2022/04/24";

const date1Result = luxon.DateTime.fromFormat(date1, "yyyy-M-dd").toJSDate()
const date2Result = luxon.DateTime.fromFormat(date, "yyyy/M/dd").toJSDate()
console.log({date1Result, date2Result})
```

(note, in moment js the solution would be similar.)

You can see for yourself by going to the luxon website and writing these lines in the dev tools console.

https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon

[image]